# Unable to start aws ssm agents service in SUSE 11

Tags: aws-ssm

I am not able to start the aws ssm agent service from SUSE 11.. there is no official rpm package for SUSE11 but after installing i was able to install but . couldn't find systemctl command to start the service!!!

Answer (score 1):

Late here, but for anyone else. Suse11 is not supported for SSM agent. Make sure to follow the prerequisites in the official documentations:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/prereqs-operating-systems.html#prereqs-os-linux